# How to unit test an application using Google Drive API (Java client)

Tags: java, google-drive-api

What is the best way to unit test an application using the [Google Drive API (Java client)](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API)?

It seems like applications written rely heavily on the [`Drive`](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.html) class, but short of either...

- creating a really extensive mock (which, itself, would likely need to
  be tested), or
- writing an integration test dependent on the actual Drive service

...how could such an application be tested?

Using mock frameworks like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) are a bit tedious with the Drive API (Java client), since usage of the Drive Java client rely on making so many chained calls (e.g., from the documentation):

```
Drive service = getDriveService(req, resp);
service.files().get(fileId).execute();
```

Comment: I'd say you are better of making integration tests in this case since you can't easily mock the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be that tedious in Mockito in fact, with the help of deep stub:

```
Drive mockDrive = mock(Drive.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

....
// stubbing
when(service.files().get(anyString()).execute()).thenReturn(something);

// verify
verify(service.files().get("Some Field ID").execute();
```

Learn more from [documentation of Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)

It is fine if you write integration test to test against the actual Drive service, but it simply cannot replace unit testing.

Comment: +1 if I wanted to sleep very happily at night, I would have unit and integration tests.

Comment: Still can't get this to work, as I get `ClassCastException (org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer$ClassWithSuperclassToWorkAroundCglibBug$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$4603175d cannot be cast to java.lang.Void)`.  However, I think your answer is actually correct, and the error I am seeing is a bug in Mockito.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis I'm running into the same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Jeffrey I haven't worked on this project in quite some time, but no, I don't think I ever did find a solution.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis I found the problem yesterday: Mockito isn't very smart about generics. `execute()` returns `T`. Mockito doesn't resolve the type variable, so it mocks `Object` instead of the real class. You can use Guava `TypeToken`'s to write a new `Answer` which gets around this problem, but it's a little messy.

Comment: just wonder if there is a simple test that can reproduce the problem?